# Android button error - array vs arraylist

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to set text to a button and I get an error with the following code:

```
public class Game extends Activity {

protected List<Button> button_list = new ArrayList<Button>();   

Button  b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, 
        b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16, b17, b18, b19, b20,
        b21, b22, b23, b24, b25;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);

    Button[] bttn_arr = new Button[] {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, 
            b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16, b17, b18, b19, b20,
            b21, b22, b23, b24, b25};

    button_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(bttn_arr));

    bttn_arr[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button_list.get(0).setText("a");
```

Why does using `button_list.get(0).setText("a")` give me an error?

I also have `button_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(bttn_arr))`

-- Doesn't this mean that `bttn_arr[0] = button_list.get(0) = b1`?

If I use `bttn_arr[0].setText("a")` it works fine.

In addition, why can't I write `button_list.get(0) = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)` ?

I was forced to write `bttn_arr[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)` instead.

Comment: What error is it giving? By the way you didn't forget the semicolumn at button_list.get(0).setText("a") right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be getting a `NullPointerException`. The reason is that although you declared button variables like b1,b2 ... You didn't create a real button object.
`bttn_arr[0].setText("a")` works fine because you assigned bttn_arr[0] a real button object by

`bttn_arr[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);`

To set a button in the ArrayList you should use

`button_list.set(0,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));`

After this you can set the text by:

```
button_list.get(0).setText("a");
```

Comment: amazing! thanks this worked perfectly. and you explained the issue perfectly too